# InDesign scripting — set the margins of the opened document

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign, margins

I've searched here and on Google but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I would like to create a (java) script that set margins according to the opened InDesign file and not create a new one.

Here is a sample code (doesn't work as I would like to):

```
var doc = app.documents.add({
    });
var page = doc.pages.item(0);
page.marginPreferences.properties = {
    top : 30,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom:30
    };
```

– This create a new document (using the default format) but I'd like the script to run on the opened file in InDesign.
How can I do this?

– I also would like to set the margins by using the size of the page. Here is an example: top margin = (width-height)/12
How could I achieve this?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Ps: sorry for my English and my low level in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var main = function() {
 var doc = app.properties.activeDocument, pgs, pg, b, w, h, m;
 if ( !doc ) return;
 pgs = doc.pages.everyItem().getElements();
 
 while ( pg = pgs.pop() ) {
  
  b = pg.bounds;
  w = Math.abs( b[3]-b[1]);
  h = Math.abs( b[2]-b[0]);
  m = Math.abs(w-h)/12;
  
  pg.marginPreferences.properties = {
   top : m,
   left: m,
   right: m,
   bottom:m
  };
 }
}

var u;

app.doScript ( "main()",u,u,UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "The Script" );
```